# tsxファイルに書いた __('x_id') を i18n-webpack-pluginで処理したい

Tags: typescript, webpack, i18n

webpack.config.dev.js へ

```
const I18nPlugin = require("i18n-webpack-plugin");
const langJa = require("./ja.json");
・・・
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
      include: paths.appSrc,
      loader: "ts"
    },
  ]
},
・・・
plugins: [
      new I18nPlugin(langJa),
    ],
```

と記載し、app.tsxに

```
console.log(__("Hello World"));
```

としたところ、

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name '__'.
```

とエラーが返ってきます。
コンソール上には こんにちは と表示されています。

おそらく i18n-webpack-plugin の処理が行われる前にTypeScriptが変換しているからだと思うのですが、TypeScriptよりも先にi18n-webpack-pluginの処理を行う方法などありますでしょうか

Comment: `declare function __(str: string): string;` こちらのコードを追加することで解決いたしました。 ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare function __(str: string): string;
```

これをソースコードへ入れてやってみてください。